# How are the layers of a solar cell stacked together?

Tags: material-science, solar-system, electronics, solar-cells

Do manufacturers of solar cell use an adhesive to bind the n-type and p-type layers of a solar cell?? Or do they simply rely on the smoothness of the surfaces of the individual layers to contact each other and conduct the electrons??

Comment: They are grown or process that way.